border-radius not applying to container element
I'm having trouble with applying border-radius to a container element in my CSS. Despite setting the border-radius property, it doesn't seem to be taking effect.
Here's my code:


* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-family: monospace;
}

.container {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.language {
list-style: none;
background: #22438C;
display:inline-block;
}

a {
display: block;
padding: 20px 25px;
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 20px;
}

ul.dropdown li {
display: block;
}

ul.dropdown {
width: 100%;
background: #22438C;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
display: none;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
background: #112C66;
}

.container:hover ul.dropdown {
display: block;
}
<div class="container">
  <a class="language" href="#">Languages ▾</a>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">German</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>




This question is similar to: Should border-radius clip the content?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Phil the problem here is that simply adding .container {overflow: hidden;} prevents the drop-down from being seen. So what I suspect @coder actually wants to know is how to make their drop-down look rounded in both the collapsed and expanded states. @coder, can you please edit your post to clarify how you want your element to look in both its collapsed and expanded states.

@BrettDonald feels like that's a separate problem

@Phil I agree that this post could be improved for better clarity, but I disagree that it is a duplicate of the other question.

@BrettDonald it's just similar (as per the comment) and it answers the question of why the border-radius on the container doesn't effect the child elements

Don’t put rounded corners on the container. Instead, put them on the <a> and the <ul>. You will need to adjust which corners are rounded on :hover, but that’s easy enough to do.


body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.language {
  list-style: none;
  background: #22438C;
  display:inline-block;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

ul.dropdown li {
  display: block;
}

ul.dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  background: #22438C;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background: #112C66;
}

.container:hover a {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.container:hover ul.dropdown {
  display: block;
}
<div class="container">
  <a class="language" href="#">Languages ▾</a>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">German</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>



